# How to get Battery Info of sony smartwatch 2?

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

Is it possible to get settings information of smart watch 2 like battery level, installed app list, vibration enabled/disabled pro grammatically? m using Control Extension API. Is there anyone know that how to get that information? using which class & API i can get this information of smart watch ? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, none of that information can be queried via the APIs.